# Android Studio dock mode

Tags: android, android-emulator

After the recent update in  Android studio, I got my emulator like this :

[Pinned simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAdtR.png)

But I would like to have it reverted to the previous version, like this :

[Unpinned simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfBjg.png)

How can I do to manage that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings->Emulator(Search for Emulator in search Box)->Uncheck "Launch in tool window"